# height: vh; does not work as it should in mobile chrome

Tags: html, css, height, viewport

Chrome is not adapting the content to the viewport

In firefox works perfectly

I tested it on Opera mini too and it is also working. But I can't post more than 2 links

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTr3.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5SL4.png)

Is it possible for chrome to adapt like opera and firefox?

```css
.intro-noticias {
  width: 100%;
  height: 89vh;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.intro-noticia-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .intro-noticia-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="intro-noticias"> 
 <div class="intro-noticia-1">
   <a href="#">
  <div class="intro-post-thumbnail">
  <div class="intro-noticia-main-caption">
   <h2></h2>
  <div>
   <span class="intro-main-caption-autor"></span>
   <span class="intro-main-caption-time"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be your `margin-top` that is throwing it off? `Calc` could be the solution

```
.intro-noticias {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px); /* The full view port height minus the margin */
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: It gone up a bit but it still does not stay 100% in the viewport.